# Css and js not working after transfered site to new server Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, css, frontend

I have moved my magento to new dedicated server ,css and js not working. Also have done static deploy,Can anyone help me to fix this issue[image]

Comment: Check mod_rewrite is enabled or not and AllowOverwrite is set to All in apache config file on new server. Also check you have .htaccess file in pub/static folder on new server if you are using apache.

Answer (score 0):

please try to remove folder from pub/static and also try to check permission on the folder, and try again by deploying commands.